# Google Maps API - Searching other locations before USA

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I wonder if someone could give me a bit of advice.

Im using Google Maps for a project im working on, what i want to be able to do is search inside australia before it searches the rest of the world.

I have a textbox and im using the following code to search.

```
function codeAddress(event) {
    var address = $("#address").val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(15);
      } else {
        errorMsg("Lookup failed: " + status);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

As an example, there is a Miami in Brisbane, Australia ... If i type Miami into the search box it returns the US miami, i need it search in Australia BEFORE searching the rest of the world.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use something called component-filtering or [region biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes) to match to addresses within a specific  country. See [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) page for details. In this case, the AU country code should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?region=AU">
```

Comment: Where would i put that, the only thing i have that calls the API is the following <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=client&sensor=true_or_false&v=3.13"></script>

Comment: Yes, right there. I have edited the answer to show exactly how to implment. The original code was not quite right. This page shows an [example of regional biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics).